# Any way to loop through data in one file on gnuplot?

Tags: loops, gnuplot

Is there any way to loop through a data file and extract specific points to plot them on the graph and then save the image on `gnuplot`?

For instance my code so far:

```
save output 'graph.$n.png'
set label 4 at $x,$y point pointtype 5
plot 'C:\Users\Desktop\testdata.dat' using 2:3 w l
```

But I want to be able to change the 'x' and 'y' to be the values contained on one line, in the second and third column of the data file, then `plot` them on the line graph, save the image, and then loop to the next line of data values. There's over 100 lines of data and I'd like a way to automate this graphing process.

All help is appreciated, thank you!!

Grace

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data.  It is much easier to understand what you are trying to do with some data as well.

Comment: Do you want to plot the whole graph on every image but label only one point on each image?

Comment: You mean `set output '...' ` am I right?

Answer (score 2):

If you have awk, type in the terminal

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1;while(i<100){printf "set term png;set output \"graph.%03d.png\";plot \"testdata.dat\" u 2:3 every 99999::"i"pt 5,\"testdata.dat\" u 2:3 w l;\n",i,i+5;i++}}' > test.plt
```

this generates the plotting file "test.plt", then open

```
gnuplot
```

and load the plotting file

```
load "test.plt"
```

Then it will generate 100 png files.

example: if the testdata.dat is the sin(x) function, you get 100 png files with serial numbers such as the figure below. For more than 100 files, replace

```
while(i<100)
```

with the appropriate value. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also do not know 'one-line' solution (without using external auxiliary file), but there is a 'prue Gnuplot' solution:

```
stats 'Grace.dat'
n=STATS_records
i=1
load 'hundreds_of_plots.plt'
```

where 'hundreds_of_plots.plt' is:

```
set term unknown
plot [i-1:i-0.5] 'Grace.dat' u 0:2
labelx=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX
plot [i-1:i-0.5] 'Grace.dat' u 0:3
labely=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX
set label 4 at labelx,labely point pointtype 5
set term png
set output "".i.'.png'
plot 'Grace.dat' u 2:3 w l
i=i+1
set output "".i.'.png'
if (i<=n) reread
```